# Navigation in Ionic 2 Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, ionic2

I have one login page and want to add a *forgot password* button, and when a user clicks it, he/she will redirect to the *forgot password page*.

here is my `login.html`

```
<button ion-button block color="blue"  
        (click)="goToSignup()" 
        class="signup-btn" 
        style="background:#45b64a;width:45%;margin:20px 2% 0;display:inline-block">
        Signup</button>
<button ion-button block color="blue" 
        (click)="goToForgotPassword()" 
        class="signup-btn" 
        style="background:#45b64a;width:45%;margin:20px 2% 0;display:inline-block">
        Forgot Password</button>
```

Here is my `login.js`

```
..
..
import {
    SignupPage
}
from '../signup/signup';
import {
    ForgotPasswordPage
}
from '../forgotpassword/forgotpassword';
Page({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/loginpage/loginpage.html'
})
export class LoginPage {

    static get parameters() {
        return [[NavController], [Http]];
    }
    constructor(nav, http, fbProvider) {
        this.login = {};
    }
    goToSignup() {
        this.nav.push(SignupPage);
    }
    goToForgotPassword(){
        this.nav.push(ForgotPasswordPage);
    }

}
```

Here is my `signup.js`

```
..
..
Page({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/signup/signup.html'
})

export class SignupPage {
    ..
    ..
}
```

Here is my `forgotpassword.js`

```
..
..
Page({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/forgotpassword/forgotpassword.html'
})

export class ForgotPasswordPage{
    ..
    ..
}
```

Navigation for Signup is working perfectly, the only issue with is with the *ForgotPassword* Navigation.

In the browser I am getting the error below.

> TypeError: self.context.goToForgotPassword is not a function
>       at _View_LoginPage0._handle_click_36_0 (LoginPage.template.js:627:28)

What is going wrong with `forgotpassword` navigation?

Answer (score 0):

Add your second page in app.module..,
in declarations and in entrycomponents..

for further details check this link

http://blog.ionic.io/10-minutes-with-ionic-2-adding-pages-and-navigation/